# Identify 1985 London photos

Tags: london, identify-this

Going through old vacation photos, and have some from London in 1985 that I can't identify. I see what appears to be an underground tube station on the right, and a number 30 bus heading to Putney.[image]

Comment: While I assume someone might locate it for you, I do not see any use for the community in doing so. The bus is clearly the topic of the photo and that you have named.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because “where in London did I take this photograph in 1985?”  is not a travel question and is neither interesting nor useful to anybody other than OP.

Comment: IMHO the two signs with the roundels are more likely to be bus stops than signalling an underground station.

Comment: The route at the time was (in the opposite direction): PUTNEY HEATH Green Man - Putney - Fulham Cross - South Kensington - Hyde Park Corner - Marble Arch - Baker Street - Marylebone Road - Euston Road - Kings Cross - Islington - Dalston - Hackney Downs - Hackney - HACKNEY WICK according to https://www.londonbuses.co.uk/_routes/current/030.html I think the red brick building in the back is probably the best hint on the picture, though I don’t recognise it (and it may be long gone by now).

Comment: @jcaron is exactly right. Look at it on Google Earth street view.

Comment: Note that the London Transport symbols on the right of the picture are I believe bus stops and not an underground station (same roundel, but the positioning on a white sign indicates a bus).

Comment: @jcaron the internet at its finest: If there's a niche interest, there's a website for it, useful when the rest of us have a query.  Many of them seem to use the same background colour too

Comment: @ChrisH RE "neither interesting nor useful" I found this interesting and am not the OP

Comment: @ChrisH you might not find it interesting. You should downvote in that case. Close votes are for off topic questions. Which this is not (see the description of [tag:identify-this]).

Comment: Note that there are 2 ChrisHs here - one found it uninteresting, the other (me) was mildly interested and delighted by the resource jcaron found. We only really overlap on Travel, so it rarely causes confusion, but I was about to vehemently disagree with comments that weren't for me

Comment: @Tim I know how to use the site, thank you very much. It may shock you to learn that I downvoted the question already, at the same time I voted to close. By my interpretation of the site scope "where is this" questions are indeed off-topic, as I think my comment made perfectly clear. You may disagree. The matter has been discussed more than once on meta without a clear consensus either way. As such I'll continue voting to close them until there is either a user consensus or a mod-team statement that such questions are on-topic. Users who disagree are perfectly welcome to vote 'Leave open'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is on Brompton Road, just off the northern corner of Harrods, looking towards what is now One Hyde Park.

[image]

Taken from [Google Street View, dated 2008](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.5003752,-0.1623811,3a,75y,64.44h,94.06t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s893D5qLiN3Z2rgElNId1sg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

Comment: Thanks for your help even if the question was perceived off topic. I appreciate the answer.